# Problema mouseListener y JTable

Tags: java, eventos

Tengo una clase en la que estoy implementando los eventos de un frame y quiero hacer que cada vez que de doble clic sobre una tabla esta abra otra ventana y me muestre los datos de ese objeto, estoy implementando la interfaz **mouseListener** a la clase y se la agrego al **Jtable** para que me ejecute el evento.

Esta es la clase donde implemento las interfaces y agrego la interfaz **mouseListener** a la tabla. **OJO**: solo pondré los eventos que implementa **mouseListener** por ser los de interés en este caso:

```
public class ControladorEstudiante implements ActionListener, KeyListener, MouseListener{

private DBConnection dbcon;

EstudianteAdmin estAdmin= new EstudianteAdmin();
MostrarEstudiante estMostrar= new MostrarEstudiante();
EstudianteDAOImpl estDAO= new EstudianteDAOImpl(dbcon);

public ControladorEstudiante(EstudianteAdmin estAdmin, MostrarEstudiante estMostrar, EstudianteDAOImpl estDAO){
    this.estDAO= estDAO;
    this.estAdmin= estAdmin;
    this.estMostrar= estMostrar;
    this.estAdmin.getTablaEstudiante().addMouseListener(this);    }

public void InicializarCrud(){

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        if(me.getClickCount()== 2){

        int fila= estAdmin.getTablaEstudiante().getSelectedRow();

        if(fila>-1){
            estMostrar.getTxtNombre().setText(estAdmin.getTablaEstudiante().getValueAt(fila, 0).toString());
            estMostrar.getTxtMatricula().setText(estAdmin.getTablaEstudiante().getValueAt(fila, 1).toString());
            estMostrar.getTxtNota().setText(estAdmin.getTablaEstudiante().getValueAt(fila, 3).toString());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

}

Como podrán saber el método que tengo para cuando de dos clic sobre la tabla es el **mouseClicked**, sin embargo, al cargar los datos de la Base de Datos en la tabla inmediatamente paso el mouse sobre el jtable, me da un error, a continuación les dejo el **stacktrace**:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
at comm.estudiante.dao.controlador.ControladorEstudiante.mouseEntered(ControladorEstudiante.java:425)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseEntered(AWTEventMulticaster.java:300)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6544)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEnterExit(Container.java:4676)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.trackMouseEnterExit(Container.java:4654)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4505)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Otra cosa es que cuando implemento la interfaz **mouseListener** sobre el Jtable, este no se selecciona, no se porque.

Comment: ¿Cual es la linea 425 de ControladorEstudiante.java???

Comment: Nada deja, ya lo vi ;-)

Comment: Es la de la implementación del método mouseEntered pero lo tengo vacío, `public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {                                       //Esta es la línea 425                                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese error te lo da por que tu mismo le has indicado que cuando suceda "mouseEntered" lance esa excepcion. Borra el metodo o implementalo ;-)

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

Si te fijas, tu IDE tuvo que porner por defecto esa implementacion.

Comment: Ahora el **mouseClicked** da un error, te dejo el stacktrace: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 >= 3
 at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
 at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:294)
 at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.convertColumnIndexToModel(SwingUtilities2.java:1988)
 at javax.swing.JTable.convertColumnIndexToModel(JTable.java:2582)
 at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2718)
 at comm.estudiante.dao.controlador.ControladorEstudiante.mouseClicked(ControladorEstudiante.java:408)`

Answer (score 1):

Uno de los inconvenientes de implementar la interfaz [`java.awt.event.MouseListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) en una clase nueva es que tienes que definir todos sus métodos en ella.

De manera que se ha incluido también en el JDK la clase [`java.awt.event.MouseAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html), la cual extiendes y sobreescribes únicamente los métodos deseados.

Por ejemplo, si estás interesado en el doble clic, el siguiente código podría darte una idea:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { "VGA", "640x480" }, { "SVGA", "800x600" } };
    Object[] columnNames = new Object[] { "Name", "Value" };
    JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getClickCount() > 1) {
                JTable table = (JTable) evt.getSource();
                int row = table.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
                TableModel model = table.getModel();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(table.getParent(), model.getValueAt(row, 0));
            }
        }
    });
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pane);

}
```

[image: ejemplo]